# 301 not redirect instead of 302 on http when open SSL Certified Website in codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, http, https, ssl-certificate

My site is develop in codeignitor. Also my site in include ssl certificate. so how can I get 301 status code when open http://www.xxxxxxx.com insted of 302.

Right now I got below status:

http://www.xxxxxxx.com
302 Found
https://www.xxxxxxx.com/
301 Moved Permanently

Please find below .htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have to be carefull, You missed to quit the "NC" on this rewrite rule you posted:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

It should be this way:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I will reassemble your .htaccess file to include the CI deault controller conditions and rules. This way you can do it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)

# Default controller change to 301
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?|index(\.php|html?)?)/?$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/?$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Change www. to 301.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule
```

Hope this is the solution you are looking for!

Comment: No problem bro.

Answer (score 0):

It's might be issue from server side. I resolve my problem from server person. So kindly contact to your server person if you face this problem.